# MAX function on one column, return all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, common-table-expression

I'm using SQL Server and I'm trying to get the `MAX` of `Res` when `Res` is a `varchar`, and I want to `group by` `pID`, but also keep the  in the final result.

```
aID | Res | pID

 1  | Yes | 94
 2  | Yes | 32
 3  | No  | 32
 4  | Yes | 94

SELECT aID, max(Res), pID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY pID
```

My final result should be:

```
aID | Res | pID
 1  | Yes | 94
 2  | Yes | 32
```

or

```
aID | Res | pID
4   | Yes | 94
2   | Yes | 32
```

The whole issue is that I can't include `aID` in the final result. I've tried a sub query where `Res` is = to `max(Res)`, but with over 50,000 records, it's taking over 20 minutes to run this thing. There's got to be a better way. Is there?

Comment: The max of a varchar seems nonsensical to me. Is the column really just "yes" or "no" or are there other words?

Comment: Just Yes and No

Comment: Using a row_number() function would be the most common way of doing this. `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pID ORDER BY CASE WHEN Res = 'Yes' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` then selecting the rows where that = 1.

Comment: @ZLK This was what I needed, thank you. If you submit it, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `MAX` and `GROUP BY`, if you have only two values '`Yes`' and '`No`' and you only want rows with `res='Yes'`

You can write your query like following using `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
;with cte as
(
    select aID, Res, pID, row_number() over(partition by pid order by aID desc) rn
    from Table1
    where res='Yes'
)
select aID, Res, pID from cte where rn=1
order by aID
```

Comment: I do want the "No" values if that is the max when grouped by pID.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by A.pID ORDER BY A.pID)As Row_Num,A.* FROM @tblName A
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  max(Res) AS Res, pID FROM @tblName GROUP BY pID
    ) B
    ON A.Res= B.Res
    AND A.pID = B.pID
) As O
WHERE O.Row_Num = 1
```

Comment: This worked, but it took over 10 minutes, so I went with the row_number() method that ZLK submitted. Thanks for taking the time though, that's a nice solution.